# How to remove same url Glide cache in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I want to load one url that returns differnet images into RecyclerView items.
Problem is all items have same image.
I'm using next RequestOptions:

```
val options by lazy {
RequestOptions()
    .signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis()))
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
    .skipMemoryCache(true)}
```

Image load:

```
fun ImageView.load() {
Glide
    .with(this)
    .asBitmap()
    .load("url")
    .apply(options)
    .into(object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(1024, 1024) {
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
            useBitmap(resource)
            this@load.setImageBitmap(resource)
        }
    })}
```

Bind ViewHolder:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(items[position])
}

class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(item: Model) = with(itemView) {
        itemView.image.load()
            ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling glide clear on your view before setting the the image, i see you aren't caching it and skipping the cache but i have had similar instances where glide try's to recycle the image.

Comment: I've already tried to 'Glide.with(imageView).clear(imageView)' and setting bitmap null, but that dosen't help'.